# error to filetransfer.download in android (erro code 1)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
//request the persistent file system
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);
}

function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path to directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory("teste_recev", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail);
    var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
    var fp = rootdir.fullPath;
    fp = fp+"/teste_recev/image_name.jpg";
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
   fileTransfer.download("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/t1.0-1/c14.4.48.48/150734_264955536974736_682293823_t.jpg",fp,  
        function(entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
            alert("download error target " + error.target);
            alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        }
    );
}
function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    console.log(parent);
}

function onDirectoryFail(error) {
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}

function fileSystemFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
```

}

```
But have a error:
```

1. dowload error source https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/t1.0-1/c14.4.48.48/150734_264955536974736_682293823_t.jpg
2. download error target//teste_recev/image_name.jpg
3. upload error code1

i have, the cordova.js in project, have link for cordova.js but have this erros if someone to help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function gotFS(fileSystem) {
           fileSystem.root.getDirectory("your dir", {create: true}, function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
                fileSystem.getFile("dummy.txt",{create: true,exclusive:false},function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
                    var path = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.txt","");
                    fileEntry.remove();
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    fileTransfer.download(FILE_DOWNLOAD_URL, path+""+your -savedName,function(theFile){
                        alert("File Downloaded Successfully " + theFile.toURI());
                    },function(error){
                        alert("File Transfer failed" + error.message);
                    });
                },fail);
            });
    }, fail);
```

Comment: One question, dummy.txt its for files *.txt our its for all files?

Comment: not only .txt files all files yaar(pdf...)...got success ah?

Comment: I have last version of cordova and you?

Comment: i need this for my university stage, the idea is to have an online file and update the site when there are changes made, I already all are missing the part after replacing the file :/

Comment: @Fabio check this one http://pastie.org/9142177 no need to change anything just copy and paste and let me know the result. Tested in both 2.9 and 3.3 versions.

Comment: the result, 0 alerts. I think the possivel net for universty, in lunch test in my home but, i have um question dbErrorHandler its a function create for you for to display errors or its to cordova.js function?

Comment: create dbErrorHandler function

Comment: I have compile program in phonegap, and test im my divice, have alerts for debug erros. I compile program, run im divice, program open, show html but alerts not show :/

Comment: I'm not noob in programming phonegap, i not add this "document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);" and program not work, sorry my bad.

But, show this 
File Transfer failed undefined

Comment: File Transfer failed undefined means you are not include the file transfer plugin in your source.

Comment: :S but i have <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script> our need more plugin?

Comment: show your config.xml file.....you need this one https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: in config.xml file i add this:     <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.2" />

Comment: check you have the above two packages in your src folder.

Comment: i dont have folder src, i have the 1 forder (name of project) did contain: my codig my code html, javascript, jquery movile, config.xml and folder css, img jquery-mobile, res and spec, i need create folder scr and past the plugin positive

Comment: its www2exampme(copy) ok, i have 
a big mistake :/

Comment: hups, i have a problem xD i have 1 folder (www) not more, i program in the notepad not eclips (and compres www, and compile in site phonegap), ok, i need the create a new project in eclips and copy my www for www of this new project right?

Comment: I dont know how to create application without eclipse. It is your wish to use eclipse.