# Unable to download pdf using phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I have created one app. in which i want the feature to  <strike>download pdf</strike>

1. my app redirects to following url when

http://www.premah.com.au/monthly-updates/

Now, when I redirect to this app from mobile's browser.i can download pdf when i click on any of pdf's poster. 
But When i am using phoneGap build to do this.Unable to download pdf i have tried following :
1. inappBrowser using window.open with _blank,_system.
2. i have tried using file-transfer plugin for downloading from absolute url of server for ex:

http://www.premah.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/apr-2014-gen-f.pdf

If you have any 100% working solution for inAppbrowser or file-transfer plugin please put code.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431890/error-to-filetransfer-download-in-android-erro-code-1/23433074#23433074

Answer (score 0):

source =  http://www.premah.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/apr-2014-gen-f.pdf

fpath = YOUR_FILE_PATH; //use filesystem to get file path.

```
 downloadBook: function(source, fpath)
 {
     var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
         fileTransfer.download(source,fpath,function(entry) {
     },
     function(error) {
         console.log("download error target " + error.code);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file-transfer cordova plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://www.premah.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/apr-2014-gen-f.pdf");

fileTransfer.download(
uri,
filePath,
function(entry) {
    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
},
function(error) {
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
},
false,
{
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
    }
}
```

);