# Failed to download and save file in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Hi Phonegap Lover/Developer,
Desperately seeking a help. My following codes throw error -

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function onFileSystemSuccess(
    fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("tmp.txt", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("tmp.txt", "");
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileEntry.remove(success, fail);
        fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(file_url), sPath + "theFile.pdf",
            function(theFile) {
                console.log("Download completed. " + theFile.toURL(), 'Success');
            }, fail);
    }, fail);
}, fail);

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error + ', Code: ' + error.code);
}
```

Btw, I've found it fails on fileTransfer.download that returns error code 2 which means  destination directory/loc is wrong. Later I discovered fileEntry.fullPath has value "/" ONLY. This happens on IOS emulator, and even on my android phone(installed and ran the apk).

Instead of having LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, Tried window.appRootDirName without any success, This seems undefined.

I want to get out of this. This became a nightmare! Appreciate your help.

Thanks
Musa

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431890/error-to-filetransfer-download-in-android-erro-code-1/23433074#23433074 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122799/phonegap-filetransfer-download/24142981#24142981 and let me know any difficulties..

Comment: Tried both just doesn't work. Still stuck on this. Really appriciate any help.